# Frame labels without a frame?

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling, output

Is there a way to add labels to a 2D plot, without the Frame ?  Here's a MWE which shows a simple graph with four labels around its frame.  I need to remove the frame, but keep the labels.  Is that possible ?

```
ParametricPlot[
    {t, t^2}, {t, -4, 4},
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}},
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {
        Style["a", 16, Italic],
        Style["b", 16, Italic],
        Style["c", 16, Italic],
        Style["d", 16, Italic]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
FrameStyle -> Directive[Opacity @ 0, FontOpacity -> 1], 
FrameTicks -> None, ...
```

[image]

But in general I'd go with `Labeled`.

Comment: How would you use `Labeled` in this case ?

Comment: @Cham What exactly triggered that question? Examples in documentation seem to be straightforward. Although I could've missed something specific to this case.

Comment: You can use `Transparent`, too.

Comment: Actually, I need to add labels to the four corners of a square losange.  The frame labels positions are just right, this is why I was trying with this option.

Comment: @Kuba, here's what I'm doing right now, using your trick (transparent frame) : http://s20.postimg.org/qkwefiesd/minkowski.jpg.  Is there a better way to add the four labels on the corners ?

Comment: @Cham `Labeled[
 ArrayPlot[DiamondMatrix[5], Frame -> None],
 {a, b, c, d}, {Top, Right, Bottom, Left}
 ]`?

Comment: @Kuba, thanks, it's working.  But how can we change the coordinates of each label ? (in case we would want to change their position)

Comment: @Cham depends what is a goal at the end. Is it more convenient for you to use graphics coordinates or only scaled in reference to the image etc etc.

Comment: Ok, I'll need to change my strategy.  I need to place some labels at different locations (coordinates) on a 2D graphics.  What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: @Cham `Inset` or `Text` in `Epilog`?